# Debug CMake project Visual Studio Code OSX

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I am following the instructions from https://medium.com/@dexterchan_44737/visual-studio-code-build-and-debug-a-c-with-cmake-on-mac-os-7633bc59bf34 but I do not accomplish to succeed.

My project folder looks like this:

```
c_cpp_properties.json
launch.json
tasks.json
build
-- ...
Challenges
--main.cpp
--CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

And some of my files are:

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {

            "name": "(lldb) Iniciar",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Challenges/DailyCoding_run",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "targetArchitecture": "x86_64",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "type": "shell",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmake",
            "command": "cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..",
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "make",
            "command": "make -j 8",
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

1. I build the project as `Tasks: Command Palette... > Run Build Task`
2. `Start Debugging`

It stops in the breakpoint but cannot click anything else as does not answer (cannot do Step Over, Step Into ...)

[image]

Comment: This looks like Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio

Comment: yes, sorry. edited